# Radio button change even not firing

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have this html which was created dynamically based on data from our database. I am trying to create a wizard so that when the user clicks a radio button, I call a webservice using ajax, and create another list of radio buttons for the user to select from.  The initial page load works fine, but when I create the dynamic radio button list that is where I am having problems with the events firing.  Do I have to reload the document, or a specific div to get this to work?

I would like to trap the "change" event when one of these radio buttons is selected. The jQuery below is not capturing the event. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<input name="productModel" id="Basic-jacketCustom" type="radio" value="Basic jacket"><label for="Basic-jacketCustom">Basic jacket</label>
<input name="productModel" id="Platinum-jacketCustom" type="radio" value="Platinum jacket"><label for="Platinum-jacketCustom">Platinum jacket</label>
<input name="productModel" id="Platinum-Pro-jacketCustom" type="radio" value="Platinum Pro jacket"><label for="Platinum-Pro-jacketCustom">Platinum Pro jacket</label>
<input name="productModel" id="Riding-jacketCustom" type="radio" value="Riding jacket"><label for="Riding-jacketCustom">Riding jacket</label>
```

jQuery:

```
$('input[name="productModel"]').change(function() {    alert("Event
 Fires"); });
```

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/yjxs36pq/ your alert needs to be on the same line maybe? Creating dynamic html elements, you will need to use .on jQuery http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What do you mean with "dynamically created"? Are you pushing the input to dom after the page load? If yes, you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Try the following example:

```js
$('body').on('change', 'input[name="productModel"]', function() {
  alert("Event Fires");
});
```

Comment: That's the fix.  Thanks, the fact that I am pushing data to the dom after initial page load was the issue.  I appreciate your quick reply, and always appreciate any advice that I receive here.

Comment: I  used `input:radio[name=productModel]:checked` , hope helps.